# How to show a dialog at any time, in any activity

Tags: android, android-handler

I would like to check every so often if exists a new version of my app, and if it´s, show a message to user. I use Firebase, connecting and comparing version from remote config with current version of app. This isn´t the problem, my problem is how to show the dialog at any time, in any activity.

I have a BaseActivity, where I have methods to connect with firebase and to show the message when it answers. Furthermore, I have a method that executes every hour this update checking:

```
    private void checkUpdate() {
        handlerCheckUpdate.postDelayed(() -> {
            getConfigFromFirebase(this);
            checkUpdate();
        }, 3600000);
    }
```

And finally I have Activity1 and Activity2 that extends of BaseActivity. In my Activity1 I start the recursive checkUpdate method.

The problem is that, if user is in Activity2 currently, when the message shows, it do it in Activity1 and not in Activity2.
What is the best solution to do this?.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I´ve found a solution. I use **AlarmManager** and **BroadcastReceiver**, and I´ve removed the recursive method *checkUpdate* and set an alarm that repeat every hour, and does the action *getConfigFromFirebase(this)*:

1. Create broadcast receiver with the action of alarm:

   ```
   public class CheckUpdateAppAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
       public static CheckUpdateReceiverListener checkUpdateReceiverListener;
       public static Boolean dialogShown = false;

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           //Alarm!!
           if (checkUpdateReceiverListener != null) {
               checkUpdateReceiverListener.onCheckUpdateListenerChanged();
           }
       }

       public interface CheckUpdateReceiverListener {
           void onCheckUpdateListenerChanged();
       }
   }
   ```
2. In BaseActivity, add create and cancel alarm methods:

   ```
   public void createAlarmCheckUpdate() {
       try {
           long firstAlarmTime = new Date().getTime();

           Intent intentAlarmCheckUpdate = new Intent(this, CheckUpdateAppAlarmReceiver.class);
           AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

           PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2000,
                   intentAlarmCheckUpdate,
                   PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
           alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, firstAlarmTime,
                   AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, alarmIntent);
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

   public static void cancelAlarmCheckUpdate(Context context) {

       AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
       Intent intent = new Intent(context, CheckUpdateAppAlarmReceiver.class);
       PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2000, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
       if (pendingIntent != null) {
           alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, implements the broadcastReceiver in BaseActivity, and override its method

   ```
   public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CheckUpdateAppAlarmReceiver.CheckUpdateReceiverListener {

   ...

   @Override
       protected void onResume() {
           super.onResume();

           CheckUpdateAppAlarmReceiver.checkUpdateReceiverListener = this;
       }
   ...

   @Override
       public void onCheckUpdateListenerChanged() {
           if (this instanceof Activity1 || this instanceof Activity2) {
               getConfigFromFirebase(this);
           }
       }
   ```

Use create and cancel alarm methods where necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a dialog in your Application class and pass the context to it.

```
class App : Application() {

    fun showAlert(context: Context) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.your_title))
                builder.setMessage(getString(R.string.your_message))
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK") { dialog, _ ->
                   dialog.dismiss()
                }
     val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
            dialog.setCancelable(false) // make it true if you want to cancel
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false)
            dialog.show()
    }
}
```

And you need to add this line in your manifest file under the application tag

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
......>
```

Call that function from any of your activity by passing context:

```
App().showAlert(YourActivity.this)
```

Comment: If I call this showAlert in my BaseActivity, I have the same problem, the dialog shows in Activity1, not in Activity2

Comment: You need to use it in your activity from where you want to display. Not in BaseActivity.

Comment: So, I need to init my timer in each activity, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android LiveData [check it here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)
The idea is - you add an observer in each of your Activities (or the BaseActivity). In the observer you add your logic for launching the Dialog. When you're ready with the update-check in the background, you notify the LiveData. The Activity that is currently in a resumed state will handle the update and show the Dialog.

```
class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() { 
...
 fun onCreate() {
   //provide your liveData from app object
   application.getVersionUpdateLiveData().(this, Observer { 
        //start your dialog here
    })
 }
}
```

Make sure you use the latest androidx lib.

Comment: The method getVersionUpdateLiveData() is my recursive method "checkUpdate", isn´t? If I do this, I would start a "Timer" for each activity, and I want start a unique Timer (from Activity1) and show the Dialog in Activity2 (or whatever that extends of BaseActivity). I think I have a bad approach, and I need use fragment or maybe background service for do that.

Comment: Not really - you should create a LiveData object, you can create it also in your app class. Than you start your checkUpdate in the background - you can do it in a Handler - it's OK. When the checkUpdate is finished you take the LiveData and trigger it's postValue() function with the result of your query for example. This postValue will trigger the onChanged() method of the observer that is currently on the UI thread. So the visible Activity will start the Dialog.

Comment: Is a good solution but I have a problem: If I check update in BaseActivity, I do it when I open each activity that extends it, so, the dialog will show in all activities. When I close an activity, the dialog is opened in the previous activity.